# Android button link to another page when login is correct

Tags: java, php, android, database

I have the code below that currently has a login of an id and password, when the link is clicked I want it to go to a profile page only if the login is correct, at the minute you can enter whatever you want or nothing at all and click Login and this will take you to the profile page. Can someone show me how I can improve my code so that the Login button will only link to the profile page if the login details are correct, according to what is in the database? I have more code that I can upload if you need it. Thanks

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

EditText doctor_number, password;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    doctor_number = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etDoctorNumber);
    password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
    final Button btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);

    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            OnLogin(v);
            //Intent profileIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Profile.class);
            //MainActivity.this.startActivity(profileIntent);
        }
    });
}

public void OnLogin(View view){
    String str_doctor_number = doctor_number.getText().toString();
    String str_password = password.getText().toString();
    String type = "Login";

    BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker(this);
    backgroundWorker.execute(type, str_doctor_number, str_password);
}
}
```

====
BackgroundWorker.java

```
public class BackgroundWorker extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    Context context;
    AlertDialog alertDialog;
    BackgroundWorker (Context ctx){
        context = ctx;
     }

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    String type = params[0];
    String login_url = "";
    String register_url = "";
    if (type.equals("Login")) {
        try {
            String doctorNumber = params[1];
            String password = params[2];
            URL url = new URL(login_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
            String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("doctor_number", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(doctorNumber, "utf-8")+"&"
            +URLEncoder.encode("password", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(password, "utf-8");
            bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
            String result ="";
            String line ="";
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                result += line;
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            return result;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else if (type.equals("Register")){
        try {
            String patient_name = params[1];
            String check_in_date = params[2];
            String room_number = params[3];
            String bed_number = params[4];
            String notes = params[5];
            URL url = new URL(register_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
            String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("patient_name", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(patient_name, "utf-8")+"&"
                    + URLEncoder.encode("check_in_date", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(check_in_date, "utf-8")+"&"
                    + URLEncoder.encode("room_number", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(room_number, "utf-8")+"&"
                    + URLEncoder.encode("bed_number", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(bed_number, "utf-8")+"&"
                    + URLEncoder.encode("notes", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(notes, "utf-8");
            bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
            String result ="";
            String line ="";
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                result += line;
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            return result;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
    alertDialog.setTitle("Login status: ");
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    if (result.contains("Login Successful")){
        Intent profileIntent = new Intent(context, Profile.class);
        context.startActivity(profileIntent);
    } else {
        alertDialog.setMessage(result);
        alertDialog.show();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
}
}
```

Comment: what about login and reg url.

Comment: I just took them out in the interest of my own privacy, they're not the issue

Comment: is Your php code  working fine?

Comment: Yes PHP is working fine, it's definitely a java problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            OnLogin(v);
        }
    });
```

Now inside BackgroundWorker.java
make following changes:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    if(result.equalsIgnoreCase("login successful")){
        Intent profileIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Profile.class);
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(profileIntent);
    } else {
        alertDialog.setMessage(result);
        alertDialog.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi I think I misunderstood you a small bit, I added your code to my code but it's still throwing an error, sorry I'm new to Java and Android and not very good. Would you mind taking a look again? Thanks so much!

Comment: the error that you might be getting is inside isDataValid() function because you did not perform your validation and did not return boolean value(true / false).

Comment: Does the code in my question now look good to you? Or should I change it? And if so what way should I change it?

Comment: Can you explain when do you call `OnLogin()` function and what does `BackgroundWorker` do?

Comment: BackgroundWorker.Java is now in the question

Comment: As far as I understand, your BackgroundWorker returns `result` to `onPostExecute()`. But what are the values that result may contain? Is it true/false, or any other value/flag

Comment: onPostExecute returns an AlertDialog with either 'login successful' or 'login not successful' when executed. However when the Intent is used to redirect to the profile page, nothing happens with onPostExecute

Comment: Hi, I think we nearly have the answer. Only error coming up now is this: MainActivity is not an enclosing class, any advice? Thank you so much!

Comment: inside BackgroundWorker replace `MainActivity.this.startActivity(profileIntent);` to `startActivity(profileIntent);` or `context.startActivity(profileIntent);`

Comment: Okay that works now for the login but it does not redirect to the profile page once login is clicked it just says "Login successful" or "Login not successful", any advice on how I can change it so that the Intent redirects to Profile? Thanks

Comment: there doesn't seems to be any issue but if it is not redirecting, there might be some spaces or other characters in result. Try replacing `if (result.equalsIgnoreCase("Login Successful")){` to `if (result.contains("Login Successful")){`   Hope it helps.

Comment: Okay my full code, as you suggested is in the original question now, can you see what the issue is? Thank you for the continuing help

Comment: Okay thanks it's working now. I didn't realise that if '(result.contains("Login Successful")){' was case sensitive, it's working now, thank you so much for all your help

Comment: Yes  `contains()` checks case sensitive values. But if you want to do case insensitive check than convert them to lower/uppercase and then perform your check. e.g. `result.toLowerCase().contains("Login Successful".toLowerCase())`

Comment: Okay thanks, I accepted your answer as the correct one, thanks for the help!

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help the other day, just one other question in relation to this, how could I change the code so that it links to a different page depending on who is logging in? For example if user enters user number '123' it links to profile A and if the user enters user number '456' it links to profile B? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to adapt this to your code:

```
public boolean verifyData(String user, String password){
    boolean authenticated = false;
    try {
        int attempts;
        Statement cmd = connection.createStatement();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM tableuserinfo";
        ResultSet res = cmd.executeQuery(query);
        String sqlUser = null;
        String sqlPsw = null;

        while(res.next()){
             sqlUser = res.getString("user");
             sqlPsw = res.getString("psw");

             if(sqlUser == user){

                 if(sqlPsw == password){
                     authenticated = true;
                     res.close();                      
                     break;
                 }
                 else{

                 }
             }
        }
    } catch (SQLException | NullPointerException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return authenticated;
    }
    return authenticated;
}
```

In these lines of code you ask the database for the username and password that you pass as parameters at the function (in your case doctor_number and password) and return true if they are correct or false if they aren't.

Comment: So should I leave my own code as is and add this? And if so where should I place it? Sorry I'm new to Java and not great just yet. Thanks

Comment: Forget my previous comment if you read it, you should do something like make a new class "DatabaseQuery" in which you put the function verifyData that you will call from the MainActivity doing something like `DatabaseQuery db = new DatabaseQuery();
db.verifyData(user,password);`

Answer (score 0):

Your java code seems fine so try putting this in your php file at the end of it

```
mysqli_close($db);         
  exit();
```

Comment: I really do not think it's the PHP because it works fine for other pages. Are you sure the Java looks good? What happens with my current code, in the question is that when I click 'Login' after entering doctor_number and password, the AlertDialog pops up saying 'login successful' or 'login not successful', but I am not brought to the profile page

Comment: have you tried exit(); once try i had the same problem